# Groovy Closure not checking owner or delegate scope

Tags: java, groovy, closures, dsl

I am writing a small `Groovy DSL`, which relies on `Groovy Closures`. I then run the `DSL` from a `Java` program by using `GroovyShell` and a `DelegatingScript`.

**Code invoking the script from Java:**

```
DelScript project = new DelScript ();

CompilerConfiguration cc = new CompilerConfiguration();
cc.setScriptBaseClass("groovy.util.DelegatingScript");
GroovyShell sh = new GroovyShell(Launcher.class.getClassLoader(), new Binding(), cc);

DelegatingScript script = (DelegatingScript) sh.parse(new File(path));
script.setDelegate(project);
script.run();
```

The instance of `DelScript` works as the `this` reference inside the script, e.g. any member or method not found in the script itself is searched in the instance of `DelScript`.

**My script can include the following expressions:**

```
create (name: "test") {
    // this code can be used to initialize the 
    // object that is created here
    testProperty = "I'm an example"
}
```

The intention of this code is to create an object and then call the closure, which can be used to initialize it. As I said before, the `create` method resides in the `DelScript` instance, (which is what I want) and it looks like this:

```
def create(arguments, configClosure) {
    // create new object
    def x = new Impl(arguments)

    // use configClosure to init it
    configClosure.delegate = x
    configClosure()
}
```

Although I set the `delegate` of the `configClosure`, I get an **error** that `testProperty` is not a part of `DelScript`. I know that the `DelScript` instance is the `this` of the `configClosure`, since I created it in the `DelScript` scope, but I thought that the closure would check references in the order: `this -> owner -> delegate`. It never checks `delegate` in my case but raises an exception right after checking `this`.

Can anyone give me some feedback on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the line

```
configClosure.delegate = x
```

Put

```
configClosure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
```